# Автоматическое воспроизведение звука без действий пользователя на странице. React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, аудио

Всем доброго времени суток!

Столкнулся со следующей задачей: при обновлении информации по сокетам необходимо воспроизводить звук - уведомление, при этом никакие действия от пользователя не ожидаются/невозможны. Как это возможно реализовать?

Буду бесконечно благодарен за помощь в решении этой головоломки :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Современные версии браузеров не поддерживают автоматическое воспроизведение аудио по загрузке страницы, этой теме уже не меньше, чем 5 лет. Ваш код успешно будет работать после того, как на странице хотя бы один раз выполнить любое пользовательское действие из ниже перечисленных:

1. Любой клик. (можно по пустому месту на странице)
2. Нажатие на любую клавишу.
3. Прокрутка. (скролл)

Движение курсором таковым действием не считается. Есть хороший вариант имитации автоматического воспроизведения звука: воспроизведение по событию наведения курсора на страницу. Срабатывает во время наведения курсора на страницу после обновления страницы браузерной кнопкой обновления. В этом случае посетитель сайта может даже не догадываться о том, что используется это событие, и при этом кажется, что звук воспроизводится автоматически после обновления страницы:

```js
document.onmouseover =_=> audio.play();
```

```html
<audio id=audio src="https://mysynthesizer.github.io/index.hetemeel/track1.mp3" controls></audio>
```

Comment: Лучший. Решение было очень простым, как оказалось, но работает безотказно. Спасибо огромное :)

Answer (score 0):

```
// Создайте аудиоэлемент
const audio = new Audio('путь_к_вашему_звуковому_файлу.mp3');

// Функция для воспроизведения звука уведомления
function playNotificationSound() {
   audio.play();
}

// Где-то в вашем коде, когда вы получаете обновление по сокетам:
socket.on('обновление',  function(data) {
   // Обработка обновления
   // Воспроизведите звук уведомления
   playNotificationSound();
});
```

Comment: "Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: play() failed because the user didn't interact with the document first." - вот в этом вся и проблема :(

Comment: Браузеры вводят ограничения, чтобы защитить пользователей от нежелательного автоматического воспроизведения аудио

Answer (score 0):

Без клика звук включить никак не получится.

Только баннер мешающий читать контент, по которому нужно кликнуть поможет.

Добавь на страницу кнопку "включить звук". При нажатии на кнопку создавай элемент аудио и ставь его на паузу.